# Check if SMA is below certain RSI level in MQL5 programming

Tags: mql4, mql5, metatrader5

I'm new to MQL5 programming and I'm trying to create my first Indicator. I would like to be able to tell if the current moving average is below level 10 in the RSI.

The image below explains what I mean.
[image]

As you can see in the picture the SMA here has a tick just below RSi level 10. The SMA is the blue line chart. How can I calculate this given I have the RSI as:

```
int rsiInstance = iRSI(_Symbol, _Period, 14, PRICE_CLOSE);
```

And the SMA as:

```
int maInstance = iMA(_Symbol, _Period, 21, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
```

So basically, a function that just returns true if that blue line touches or is below RSI Level 10 and false otherwise. Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the `iRSI` and the `iMA` only return handles for calling them. Those are their definitions: what parameters should be involved when calculating them? See [here](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/indicators/ima)

You'll need to create a dynamic array as a buffer and copy the returned values into that array. Then you'll have the actual values available from that array.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t specific, I do have this array with all the values, I just dont know how to calculate the above as shown in the picture with all those values in tje array

Answer (score 0):

I am also not a pro but I think you need to parse the rsi and ima handle into array buffer something like this.

```
bool checkiMALevel() {
     //RSI Buffer
   int rsiInstance = iRSI(_Symbol, _Period, 14, PRICE_CLOSE);
   double rsiBuffer[];
   CopyBuffer(rsiInstance, 0, 1,3,rsiBuffer); // stores rsi of last 3 candles 
   ArraySetAsSeries(rsiBuffer, true);
   
   //IMA Buffer
   int maInstance = iMA(_Symbol, _Period, 21, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE); // stores ima of last 3 candles
   double imaBuffer[];
   CopyBuffer(maInstance, 0, 1,3, imaBuffer);
   ArraySetAsSeries(imaBuffer, true);
   
   if (rsiBuffer[0] < 10 && imaBuffer[0] < 10) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
```

And Call it wherever you want

```
bool isIMAUnderTenRsi = checkiMALevel();
```